# xlwings: how to reference a cell and use the value in that cell as a row range value

Tags: python, excel, delete-row, xlwings

I have the below excel function which looks for the last cell number in a row and equates it in cell 'L1' as a number eg 56055:

sheet.range('L1').value  = '=(MATCH(REPT("B",2), A:A))-2'

I want to use the number eg 56055 in cell 'L1' to come up with a code like below:

sheet.range('C17:K56055').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft)

Additional info: I have multiple statements which I am automating and I need to delete some cells from 'C17' to the last row with useable data hence 'K56055'. The Ageing reference in this case will be in row 56057 and I need to see this.

With VBA it's pretty simple but I need it in xlwings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to execute the line
sheet.range('C17:K**XXXXX**').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft)
where **XXXXX** is replaced with the value in Cell 'L1'?

The value in cell 'L1' can be obtained using the value attribute. It may be necessary to set the value to int

```
cell_value = int(sheet['L1'].value)
```

Then just use the returned value in string format

```
sheet.range('C17:K{0}'.format(cell_value)).api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft)
```

Comment: Thank you moken. Just what I needed.